# How do i pass dynamic arguments to html included via iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I am having two html files. One file should include the source of other file like this.

**file1.html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <span>Hello #{bean.name}</span>
    </ >
</html>
```

**file2.html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="file1.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Inside iframe i want to display a string "Hello John" depending upon the user. How to pass the parameter name to file1.html

Comment: Looks more like a JSF problem to me than JavaScript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="file1.html?user=John"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, in `file1`, you could your server-side language of choice (e.g. PHP) to safely take that value from the query string and put it on the page. Alternatively, you could [use JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery) to take the value from the query string.

Either way, **make sure the value is properly escaped(!!!)** to avoid XSS attacks.

Comment: think you are right but still not sure +1 for making me research on what i thought to be a wild goose !!

Comment: How to include query string straightly into html without setting in bean. Something like this 'Hello <%=user%>'

Comment: @Kaplana, could you restate your question?